# How can I tell if an iOS game uses iCloud Drive?

Tags: ios

I recently got a used iPad to do some "mobile" gaming. I want to move some of my in-progress games from my iPhone to the iPad. I don't want to do a full restore because the devices have dramatically different storage sizes (the iPhone backup probably wouldn't "fit"). I also intend to set up the iPad differently and just don't need everything restored (like Settings).

**How can I tell if a game uses iCloud Drive to backup/sync progress, saves, characters, or any other kinds of game data?**

I don't want to download each and every game onto the iPad to check, not only because that sounds like a lot of work, but I'm not sure what'll happen if an iCloud Drive syncing app shows up on two active devices at once.

Is it foolproof to look under Settings | General | Storage & iCloud Usage | Manage Storage | "App" and see if it has a "Documents & Data" item? For example, here is Transistor's screen:

[image]

Comment: Kind of similar question on the [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/245519/how-can-i-tell-whether-an-ios-game-app-saves-its-data-to-icloud)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > iCloud > Manage storage > Backups > This iPad (it will be iPhone for you).